# Not loading static Resources in Spring boot, Thymeleaf and AngularJs app

Tags: spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a Spring Boot project which has to start an angular spa. The structure of the resource folder is the following:

[image]

In the templates/src folder there is the index.html file I start with the controller:

```
@RequestMapping("/")
String index() {
    return "src/index";
}
```

in this way I successfully start the index.html but all the resurces under:

- bower_components
- src/js
- src/css

are not loaded correctly. So I added configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcAutoConfiguration.WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(WebConfig.class);

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler(    "/js/**")
                .addResourceLocations(  "/templates/src/js/");
    }
}
```

but I still not able to load all the needed resources cause I get 404

[image]

I do not understand what I am doing wrong.

Here goes also the index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" data-ng-app="app">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Angular version | Angulr</title>
  <meta name="description" content="Angularjs, Html5, Music, Landing, 4 in 1 ui kits package" />
  <meta name="keywords" content="AngularJS, angular, bootstrap, admin, dashboard, panel, app, charts, components,flat, responsive, layout, kit, ui, route, web, app, widgets" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" type="text/css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../bower_components/animate.css/animate.css" type="text/css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" type="text/css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../bower_components/simple-line-icons/css/simple-line-icons.css" type="text/css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font.css" type="text/css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body ng-controller="AppCtrl">
  <div class="app" id="app" ng-class="{'app-header-fixed':app.settings.headerFixed, 'app-aside-fixed':app.settings.asideFixed, 'app-aside-folded':app.settings.asideFolded, 'app-aside-dock':app.settings.asideDock, 'container':app.settings.container}" ui-view=""></div>


  <!-- jQuery -->
  <script src="../bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Angular -->
  <script src="../bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>

  <script src="../bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
  <script src="../bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js"></script>
  <script src="../bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
  <script src="../bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
  <script src="../bower_components/angular-touch/angular-touch.js"></script>

  <script src="../bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script> 
  <script src="../bower_components/ngstorage/ngStorage.js"></script>
  <script src="../bower_components/angular-ui-utils/ui-utils.js"></script>

  <!-- bootstrap -->
  <script src="../bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
  <!-- lazyload -->
  <script src="../bower_components/oclazyload/dist/ocLazyLoad.js"></script>
  <!-- translate -->
  <script src="../bower_components/angular-translate/angular-translate.js"></script>
  <script src="../bower_components/angular-translate-loader-static-files/angular-translate-loader-static-files.js"></script>
  <script src="../bower_components/angular-translate-storage-cookie/angular-translate-storage-cookie.js"></script>
  <script src="../bower_components/angular-translate-storage-local/angular-translate-storage-local.js"></script>

  <!-- App -->
  <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  <script src="js/config.js"></script>
  <script src="js/config.lazyload.js"></script>
  <script src="js/config.router.js"></script>
  <script src="js/main.js"></script>
  <script src="js/services/ui-load.js"></script>
  <script src="js/filters/fromNow.js"></script>
  <script src="js/directives/setnganimate.js"></script>
  <script src="js/directives/ui-butterbar.js"></script>
  <script src="js/directives/ui-focus.js"></script>
  <script src="js/directives/ui-fullscreen.js"></script>
  <script src="js/directives/ui-jq.js"></script>
  <script src="js/directives/ui-module.js"></script>
  <script src="js/directives/ui-nav.js"></script>
  <script src="js/directives/ui-scroll.js"></script>
  <script src="js/directives/ui-shift.js"></script>
  <script src="js/directives/ui-toggleclass.js"></script>
  <script src="js/controllers/bootstrap.js"></script>
  <!-- Lazy loading -->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Update the resource location to point to your classpath.

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/js/**")
            .addResourceLocations("classpath:/templates/src/js/");
}
```

Spring Boot also adds static content automatically from the following classpath locations:

- `/META-INF/resources`
- `/resources/`
- `/static/`
- `/public/`

Source: [Serving Static Web Content with Spring Boot](https://spring.io/blog/2013/12/19/serving-static-web-content-with-spring-boot)

Comment: Worked, but i don't get it. Isn't /src/main/resources/static/** the place where spring-boot would search by default?! Then we have to add the Bean. Ok. But then this classpath: thing - using spring mvc itself is not needed.