# failed to GET resources/static/bower_components/angular/angular.js on Spring Boot project?

Tags: angularjs, spring, spring-security, spring-boot, bower

I am learning spring boot and spring security with angularjs.

previously I use CDN to load angular in my html, everything just fine.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular-messages.js"></script>
```

but many people said using `bower` is better so I want to give it a try.
I've installed bower, set the diretory to `resources/static/bower_components`, install the dependencies, and change the script.

```
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-messages/angular-messages.js"></script>
```

but, when I load the html, it said failed 404. When I tried it on the web, `Whitelabel Error Page` error occured.

As I know, everything in `resources/static` will be publicly available? Why I cannot access it?

**--EDIT--**

I am trying a solution from [Not loading static Resources in Spring boot, Thymeleaf and AngularJs app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29918732/not-loading-static-resources-in-spring-boot-thymeleaf-and-angularjs-app), but still failed.

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcAutoConfiguration.WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/bower_components/**")
                .addResourceLocations(classpath:"/static/bower_components/");
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the directory exactly? Is it `src/main/resources/static` or is it just `resources/static` in relation to your project root?

Comment: yes, it is `src\main\resources\static\bower_components`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved it. The solution is to delete your project from `Package Explorer` in Eclipse and import it again from `File->Import`.

A simpler solution is to refresh your project in Eclipse (Right click on your project -> choose `Refresh (F5)`)